# Convert a byte array into an int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, int, byte

Is there was a way to convert a hole array of bytes (lets say 1024) into an int array of total 256 integers without using something similar to this:

```
int result = 0;   
    result = b[0] & MASK;
    result = result + ((b[1] & MASK) << 8);
    result = result + ((b[2] & MASK) << 16);
    result = result + ((b[3] & MASK) << 24);            
return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

An *int array*?  No, there isn't.  You might be able to get other APIs that are *similar* to arrays, but even so they'll be doing something like that underneath.  For example, `ByteBuffer.wrap(array).asIntBuffer()` would do that: it'd give you an array-like API, but underneath it'd be doing exactly what you say.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unsafe but probably shouldn't

```
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }


    byte[] bytes = new byte[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) bytes[i] = (byte) i;
    int[] ints = new int[bytes.length / Integer.BYTES];
    UNSAFE.copyMemory(bytes, Unsafe.ARRAY_BYTE_BASE_OFFSET, ints, Unsafe.ARRAY_INT_BASE_OFFSET, bytes.length);
    for (int i : ints)
        System.out.printf("%08x%n", i);
```